# In Windows Classic theme the buttons on toolbars have no borders

Tags: front-end, dialog-window, appearance

This is under Mathematica 13.0 and Windows 11:

[image]

In Preferences, the situation is even worse:

[image]

Since all those windows are Mathematica notebooks, maybe it is possible to fix them?

Comment: I've only seen this happen on 4th generation Intel machines using their integrated graphics.  If that is the case, evaluating `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd,{"RenderingOptions","PreferredGPU"}]="Software"` and restarting the application should fix it.

Comment: @ihojnicki ...and will there be a way to revert it? The graphics is AMD Radeon though and I think this is unrelated to graphics subsystem...

Comment: To revert it, just replace `"Software"` with `Inherited`.

Comment: @ihojnicki okay, this did not change anything.

Comment: @ihojnicki in options inspector there is no option "Inherited". There are "Integrated" and "Automatic" (which was by default).

Comment: `Inherited`, without the double quotes.  That resets the option back to the default.

Comment: @ihojnicki okay. The option does not affect the appearance...

Comment: Then there probably isn't much that can be done.  Other than reverting to the stock theme for Windows.

Comment: "isn't much that can be done" is a strong statement, @anixx you always have the chance to contact Wolfram Support.

Comment: @rhermans, having insider knowledge helps in situations like this. Anixx, if you contact support, please make sure you include all of the customizations you've made and what versions you used.